# Flask on azure - 500 internal server error

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am new to python. I am trying to create a web page which takes 1 file as input, does a look with an existing file stored in static folder and then return the result in an excel. When I run the file on virtual environ using "flask run" then, It is executing properly.
However when I run the same application on Azure app service then, I am getting 500 internal server error "The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application." after click on submit button.
Appreciate if you can advise on this.

```
### My Python code
from operator import index
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file, make_response
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import FileField, SubmitField
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
import io
import pandas as pd
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'supersecretkey'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'static/files'

class UploadFileForm(FlaskForm):
    file = FileField("File", validators=[InputRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")

@app.route('/', methods=['GET',"POST"])
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET',"POST"])

def home():
    form = UploadFileForm()
      if form.validate_on_submit():
         file = form.file.data # First grab the file
         prop_file = os.path.join('static/files','abc.xlsx')
         df1 = pd.read_excel(prop_file)
         df_Check = pd.read_excel(file)

          # format assoc to remove any special characters
         df_Check['New_Assoc_No'] = df_Check.ASSOCIATION_NO.str.replace('\W', '')
         df1['New_Assoc_No'] = df1.ASSOCIATION_NO.str.replace('\W', '')

         # format name to remove any special characters
         df_Check['NewName'] = df_Check.NAME.str.replace('\W', '')
         df1['NewName'] = df1.NAME.str.replace('\W', '')

         df_dup_assoc = pd.merge(df_Check,df1, on="New_Assoc_No", how="inner")
         df_dup_name = pd.merge(df_Check,df1, on="NewName", how="inner")

         out = io.BytesIO()
         with pd.ExcelWriter(out, engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
              df_dup_assoc.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name= "Assoc")
              df_dup_name.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name= "Name")
         writer.save
         writer.close
         out.seek(0)


    #display result on a new page
         return send_file(out, attachment_filename="dup.xlsx", as_attachment=True)
return render_template('index.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: i would tag the question as azure

Comment: Check the terminal / log for the error traceback!

Answer (score 0):

After checking the log I figured that there was an issue with dependencies. Upgraded the package and it got solved. thanks Klaus D. for suggestion

Comment: which log did you check? I'm just asking because you're not setting up or writing any logs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).